# C++でのchar型とint型の演算について

Tags: c++

C++言語で、char型というのが有りint型と演算をすると、結果はint型になると聞いたのですが、試しに

```
bool ex1,ex2;
ex1 = '1' == ('0' + 1);
ex2 = '1' == 1;
cout << ex1 << endl;
cout << ex2 << endl;
```

とすると、結果は

```
1
0
```

と表示されてしまいました。ex1もint型になるというので有れば、同じ結果を与えると思うのですが上記2つの論理演算の結果が異なっているのはC++言語のどの様な仕様に基づいて処理されたからなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C++言語で、char型というのが有りint型と演算をすると、結果はint型になると聞いた

あくまで`char`で表している文字コードの値に変換されます。`char`の`'1'`は`int`の`49`へ変換されます。

```
ex2 = '1' == 1;
```

は

```
ex2 = 49 == 1;
```

であり`false`が得られます。

Comment: そうなのですね。それを踏まえると'0'はintの48なので、それに1を足してintの49となり論理演算がtrueとなるという理屈で両者の違いに納得が行きました。ありがとうございました！